# Weird C++ memory issue. Const pointer being changed

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, pointers

Solution Found

Problem description:
I was using an old C library and had a class that was receiving a const char * as an argument in a function. The function was creating a dynamic object and storing it in a linked list using the const char * as an argument.

The problem was that after doing so, the const char * that was passed to the function was modified in memory outside of the class. This destroyed the data in the Node.

The Solution:
Use std::string as the data types in the Classes. When the const char * is passed to the string as a value the string takes care of the memory management for you.

What I learned?
When using C++ always use Strings and ONLY use char * with a string.c_str() if it is needed in some C library.

Thanks guys. You saved my weekend.

Comment: Can you come up with a much smaller example that exhibits the same problem? The code you linked is much too large for us to figure out what's wrong with it...

Comment: At SO, your question must be self-contained, not refer to some external web site. So you really need to trim your code and post a relevant snippet, preferably a proper SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can't you just use std::map rather than trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: You can use a memory breakpoint with your debugger to catch the code chaning your data.

Comment: -1 Please don't "link the entire thing" -- you're basically saying your time is too important to bother reducing the problem to a manageable size, so you expect everyone else to do it for you.

Comment: your code is complete, but it is ill indented, and we cannot even change that to facilitate our task. Post your code here instead of pastebin, and choose a more compact coding style (open brace at end of line K&R style would help). That said, check line 113, and ask yourself what happens when there's only 1 element in your list.

Comment: I apologize guys. The problem is that I did not know how to reduce the problem to a workable question. I've been working on this for more than a day and couldn't pin point the actual problem, so as a result, I was not able to post a snippet. It wasn't out of lazyness as Jonathan so kindly assumed. I have found the solution and I am posting it in the question in case someone else comes across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buff is created on the stack. You pass buff to Cache.find, where eventually it becomes the key of your node. The next time you handle a connection the memory occupied by buff has been reused because you've exited the function where buff was declared. So your key disappears/gets trashed. Fundamentally you have pointers to memory which is no longer valid.

This is exactly why you shouldn't try to roll your own, but instead use std::map.

Plus you seem to have multiple threads modifying global variables without any synchronization.

Comment: I think this is the problem. I am very new to C++ programming and I basically don't know where to start. If I have a const char *, how can I copy it into a new const char * that will be safe from tampering?

Comment: No, you use std::string, then you **don't have to worry about it**. It will handle the memory for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was my problem. I was having issues dealing with a C library, so I tried to use char * in as many places as I could in the program. Changing the element types to std::string and simply returning string.c_str() fixed the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

You could boil that down much further. From skimming over the code, this is my guess. Essentially, what you are doing wrong is this:

```
const char* a;
{
  std::string f("foo");
  a = f.c_str();
}
doSomethingWith(a);
```

My advice: move away from `char*` completely. If there are places where you absolutely must use them, learn about object lifetime and how keeping a pointer does not extend that lifetime in any way. I don't mean “don't use `char*` until you understand them better” – I think that I understand them just fine and still avoid using them when I can. I mean “use them if you're working with C code (or C++ code that in this respect looks like C code).”

Additionally, the comments above are absolutely true. Trim down your problem as far as possible (that may give you the answer already) and describe it here, in a self-contained way.